# Node won't upgrade beyond v6.11.2

Tags: node.js, path

When I run `node -v` I see:

```
node -v
v6.11.2
```

I run `brew update`, `brew upgrade`, and update all npm modules every morning when I turn on my MacBook. I have npm 6.4.1.

I went to the [Node downloads website](https://nodejs.org/en/download/), downloaded the installer, and installed v10.13.0. `node -v` still says v.6.11.2. I restarted my computer, ran the install again, no change.

I think I see the problem. When I run `echo $PATH` is see:

```
/Users/TDK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin:
/Users/TDK/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@global/bin:
/Users/TDK/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin:
/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin:
/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/TDK/google-cloud-sdk/bin:
/usr/local/heroku/bin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/Users/TDK/.rvm/bin
```

`/usr/local/bin` is the path to Node, so that's good. But above it is a path to `/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin`. I need to get rid of that path. I opened `/etc/paths` and saw:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

It looks like I have another `paths` file somewhere. All those paths above `/usr/local/bin` were installed when I was in coding bootcamp, I can get rid of all of them. Where might this other `paths` file be? I tried Spotlight to search for the first path, it couldn't find any file containing that string.

It looks like these are all path for one specific user `/Users/TDK/` (that's me), not global paths for all users. Is there somewhere in `/Users/TDK/` with paths? I commented out  and then deleted lines involving RVM in the following files, without fixing the problem.

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

I checked these files but didn't see anything suspicious:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/bashrc
```

Another thought is that `nvm` is causing the problem. The path

```
/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin:
```

is the problem. Maybe instead of removing this path I can alter `nvm` to point to the latest version of node?

Comment: Remove the Homebrew-installed Node.js, and (possibly) re-install from the official installer. And make sure that it's not caused by `nvm` (run `nvm current` on the command line and see if that returns anything).

Comment: You have nvm installed. Check nvm's way of updating default node version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to remove node 6.11.2 from your computer?

If not, just run `nvm install node`. That will install the lastest node, if you want to install a specific version, run `nvm install 10.10.0` instead

Then run `nvm use node` or `nvm run node --version`

Comment: "nvm install node" worked! The path "/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/bin" had set my computer to always use Nodse v6.11.2. I didn't need to delete the path, I just needed to change the path, which now reads "/Users/TDK/.nvm/versions/node/v11.2.0/bin". The nvm documentation says that "nvm install node" will "download, compile, and install the latest release of node". I'll put "nvm install node" into my checklist for regular software updates.